# How to Resize Dialog Box in LWUIT?

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-dialog

I have Created one Program Using Lwuit,Midlet. In that program I am showing Dialog box on the screen (LWUIT component) when I press mobile key. It shows default size. But I want to resize it.

How can I resize the Dialog Box in **LWUIT**?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this [Dialog#Show](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Dialog.html#show%28int,%20int,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29) method for showing resized Dialog. For example,

```
Dialog dialog = new Dialog("Information");
dialog.show(0, 100, 11, 11, true);
```

Comment: yes i got it bharath. again i want to close it.when i press some other key. i tried with dialog.Dispose(); . but it is not working.

Comment: Dont use `Dispose()`. use [`dialog.dispose();`](http://lwuit.java.net/javadocs/com/sun/lwuit/Dialog.html#dispose())

Comment: Shankar @bharath answer is OK.You should accept the answer who resolve your question.

Comment: Just update your code on your answer. Dont use comment for this.

Comment: --> d is an Object for dialog()                                 public void keyPressed(int key){                          switch(key)
     { -->50-55,57 are represents 2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9
                case 50:
                case 51:
                case 52:
                case 53:
                case 54:
                case 55:
                case 57:
                    d.show(180, 30, 5, 5, true);
                    break;   
                case 56:
                case 42:
                case 35: --> key #
                    d.dispose();
                    break;
         }

Comment: Have you debug your application? use `system.out.println` inside of case 35 and see the output. I think case 35 not executed.

Comment: So you need to find which is `#` key code. and use it inside that case. Also dispose inside of default case.