# How can I Dispose Dialog box From LWUIT Component

Tags: java-me, lwuit, lwuit-dialog

I am developing one project using LWUIT, Midlet mobile Application. when I press number keys a dialog box will open. when i press the keys #,0,* Dialog should be close.
I am using `Dialog.dispose()` method to close dialog. But it is not working. Below is my Code. Can anyone tell me what is the problem in my code?

```
public class javaForm extends Component implements ActionListener
{

Dialog d=new Dialog();


public void keyPressed(int key){

     System.out.println("Key pressed :"+key);

            switch(key)
            {


                case 48:
                    d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 49:
            d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 50:
            d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 51:
             d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 52:
             d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 53:
            d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 54:
            d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 55:
             d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 57:
                    d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                    break;
                case 56:
                     d.show(130,20,30,30,true);
                      break;
                case 42:
            d.dispose();
                        break;
                case 35:
                        d.dispose();
                        break;
                default:
                       d.dispose();
                       break;
            }

}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) 

{

 throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");

}

}
```

Actually javaForm is a java Program developed using **LWUIT** and am calling this javaForm inside of **MIDLET** which is javaForm1. I Included all the Necessary packages.

Comment: you should accept your other questions before asking new

Comment: Have you check the key code for that keys? [Already I told you](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8799366/how-to-resize-dialog-box-in-lwuit) to use println inside of the case and see what happened.

Comment: yes @ Bharath. i tried , but not Works.i pressed key 2 and it displayed 50. again i pressed 2 it doesn't print anything

Comment: Totally agree with @frayab.You must accept other questions. It is important if you want to get answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why don´t you use `Form.addGamekeyListener()`?

Put the `gameKeyListener` in yout `Form` (extends `ActionListener` in the `Form`)and later in the `actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae)` capture the key with `ae.getKeyEvent` and close the `Dialog`.

Map the GameKeys with `Canvas`. For example: `Canvas.FIRE`.

Comment: @ jmunoz.. what are the keys comes under GameKeyListener.I want Use all of the mobile Keys to show Dialog,to Dispose Dialog..

Comment: Use addKeyListener instead of game key listener just as jmunoz explained. You can also subclass dialog and override the keyReleased callback.

Comment: For what? Form.addKeyListener() is like game key listener. Overriding a method is just deriving LWUIT's Form and declaring public void keyReleased(int keyCode) {...}